# How do I conditionally remove columns from my dataframe without using for loops?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter an AppleStore.csv dataframe based on price. I want to create a 'new' dataframe with the condition that only free apps are included. Below is the code I used to filter the same condition on a googleplaystore.csv app dataframe and it worked fine.

```
import numpy as np


df_A = pd.read_csv("AppleStore.csv") 
df_G = pd.read_csv('googleplaystore.csv')

df_G.dropna(axis = 0, how = "any", inplace = True)

df_gg = df_G[df_G.Price == '0'] # df_gg is the new google apps df with only free apps

df_apple = df_A[df_A.price == '0.0']
```

when I run the code above, it returns only the column header row and the error message:

```
C:\Users\Dan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py:253: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  res_values = method(rvalues)
```

I am quite uncertain as to what to do. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is there are numeric columns or mixed numeric with strings. So try compare by `0` instead string `'0'`, `'0.0'` if all columns are numeric:

```
df_gg = df_G[df_G.Price == 0] 
df_apple = df_A[df_A.price == 0]
```

If mixed types because replace missing values to `0` numeric try convert to numeric columns:

```
df_G.Price = df_G.Price.astype(float)
df_A.Price = df_A.Price.astype(float)
```

And then compare:

```
df_gg = df_G[df_G.Price == 0] 
df_apple = df_A[df_A.price == 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're comparing a string to a integer or float column:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'price' : [0,1]})

df1[df1.price == '0']

 FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  res_values = method(rvalues)
```

Where as :

```
df1[df1.price == 0]


 price
0   0
```